# Problem with printing the correct item from a 3rd array when comparing two arrays

Tags: java, arrays

I am trying to write a shopping list program where the user enters in items on a shopping list with corresponding prices. I have used a String array for the items on the shopping list and a double array for the prices. At the end, the program should print out the most expensive item and the least expensive item.

To do this I made a copy of the price array. Then sorted the original price array using `Arrays.sort()` so it rearranged in ascending order. After that, I used a for loop to compare the duplicate price array with the sorted original array and when the value in the duplicate is the same as the lowest/highest value in the sorted array I printed the shopping item in the corresponding position from the string array.

This doesn't seem to work exactly as the String being printed doesn't always correspond to the exact position, as it should according to my logic. I cannot figure out where I'm going wrong. I think the problem lies in the `getCheapestItem()` and `getMostExpensiveItem()` methods.

**Edit:**
There might be better ways to do it, like using List or ArrayList, but I need to solve it using Arrays only.

Main class:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;

    public class Main {

    static Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    static int listSize;
    static String[] sl;
    static double[] price;
    static double [] price_duplicate;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Fruit fruit = new Fruit();

        shoppingList();
        sl = new String[listSize];
        price = new double[listSize];

        //Loop asking user to enter items and prices
        for(int i = 0; i <= listSize - 1; i++)
        {
            System.out.println("Enter item " + (i+1) + ":");
            fruit.setName(scanner.nextLine());
            sl[i] = fruit.getName();

            System.out.print("Price of " + sl[i] + ":");
            fruit.setPrice(scanner.nextDouble());
            scanner.nextLine(); //calling nextLine() to get rid of the         newline character
            price[i] = fruit.getPrice();
        }
        //Loop printing items and their prices
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("-Your shopping list-");
        for(int i = 0; i <= listSize - 1; i++)
        {
            System.out.println(sl[i] + " cost " + price[i]);
        }
        System.out.println();

        //Duplicate the price array
        price_duplicate = price;

        //Order the array in ascending order so as to be able to easily     access lowest and highest values in the array
        Arrays.sort(price);

        //Identify the cheapest and most expensive items on the shopping list
        getCheapestItem();
        getMostExpensiveItem();

    }

    static int shoppingList(){
        System.out.print("Enter the number of items in your shopping list:");
        listSize = scanner.nextInt();
        scanner.nextLine(); //calling nextLine() to get rid of the newline     character
        return listSize;
    }

    //Method to match the lowest price in the sorted array to its equivalent     value in the duplicate of the original array and print the corresponding string from the sl array, thus identifying the cheapest item on the list
    static void getCheapestItem(){
        Arrays.sort(price);
        for(int i = 0; i < price_duplicate.length; i++){
            if(price_duplicate[i] == price[0])
            {
                System.out.println(sl[i] + " cost(s) " + price[0] + " and is/are the cheapest item(s) on the list.");
            }
        }
    }
    //Method to Match the highest price in the sorted array to its equivalent value in the duplicate of the original array and print the corresponding string from the sl array, thus identifying the most expensive item on the list
    static void getMostExpensiveItem(){
        Arrays.sort(price);
        for(int i = price_duplicate.length - 1; i >= 0; i--){
            if( price_duplicate[i] == price[price.length - 1])
            {
                System.out.println(sl[i] + " cost(s) " + price[price.length -1] + " and is/are the most expensive item(s) on the list.");
            }
        }
    }




}
```

Fruit class:

```
public class Fruit {
    private String name;
    private double price;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public double getPrice() {
        return price;
    }

    public void setPrice(double price) {
        this.price = price;
    }
}
```

Comment: Not directly relevant, because this is obviously just a school assignment, but for future reference: `double` is an inappropriate numeric type to use for storing money. If you want a number that behaves the way humans count, using decimal (base 10) numbers, then you'll need a decimal number type. In Java that's `BigDecimal`. For more information, see https://floating-point-gui.de/ .

Comment: hi, did you tried my answer? if you found it useful please consider to mark it as accepted by clicking the green tick in the left of the answer. your small step will help others to find a useful solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess your problem lies in making a copy/duplicate of the price array. You are using `price_duplicate=price;` which actually not making copy of the price array contents, but just references/points to the same price array object with the duplicate array.

As a result, when you are sorting the original price array, your duplicate array also get sorted. There are several [ways](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/array-copy-in-java) to copy an array object to another.

But I would suggest you to use one of your existing code flow, when you are inserting the prices into the original **price** array, you can also insert them into the duplicate array.

After the 
`price[i]=fruit.getPrice();`
just add 
`price_duplicate[i]=fruit.getPrice();`

And don't forget to initialize the duplicate array as like you initialized the original price array before.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I found it very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you are using two arrays, since that makes things more complicated. I would go for a single list `static List<Fruit> fruits;`.

Then reading the items could be simplified too:

```
    for(int i = 0; i <= listSize - 1; i++)
    {
        System.out.println("Enter item " + (i+1) + ":");
        name = scanner.nextLine();

        System.out.print("Price of " + sl[i] + ":");
        price = scanner.nextDouble();
        scanner.nextLine(); //calling nextLine() to get rid of the         newline character

        fruits.add(new Fruit(name, price));
    }
```

Of course this means `Fruit` needs a constructor that requires both name and price. `name` and `price` should be defined outside of the loop.

To do the sorting you could use a `Comperator<Fruit>`.

```
Comperator<Fruit> compareByPrice = (Fruit f1, Fruit f2) ->
        f1.getPrice().compareTo(f2.getPrice());
```

To sort ascending:

```
Collections.sort(fruits, compareByPrice);
```

To sort descending:

```
Collections.sort(fruits, compareByPrice.reversed());
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to complicate things. You can get cheapest and expensive fruits through fruit objects itself. Look at below example. Create list of Fruit objects. Than do Collections.sort. In Collections.sort you can provide your implementation of Comparator (way to sort any object). In you case sorting has to be done by price. After sorting you can find cheapest fruit in first index and expensive one in last index

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.List;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        List<Fruit> fruitList = new ArrayList<>();
        fruitList.add(new Fruit("orange", 3.2));
        fruitList.add(new Fruit("apple", 9.5));
        fruitList.add(new Fruit("banana", 7.4));
        fruitList.add(new Fruit("grapes", 1.3));

        Collections.sort(fruitList, new Comparator<Fruit>() {
            @Override
            public int compare(Fruit o1, Fruit o2) {
                if (o1.getPrice() < o2.getPrice()) {
                    return -1;
                } else if (o1.getPrice() > o2.getPrice())
                {
                    return 1;
                } else {
                    return 0;
                }
            }
        });
        System.out.println("Cheapest fruit " + fruitList.get(0).getName());
        System.out.println("Expensive fruit " + fruitList.get(3).getName());


    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer. I'm a beginner and Lists haven't yet been covered in the course that I'm doing. That is why I have tried to solve this problem using arrays. My problem is that I cannot understand why the code I've written won't identify the correct item from the shopping list as being the most/least expensive.

Answer (score 0):

You use illegal organisation. You should split your code with following parts:

- Implement `Fruit` class, that contain full infromation about single fruit
- Implement method, that using console retrieves list of fruits
- Define actions to be applied for given list of fruits: get fruits with minimum/maximum prices
- Output results.

---

This is `Fruit` class implementation. It is *immutable*.

```
public final class Fruit {

    private final String name;
    private final double price;

    public Fruit(String name, double price) {
        this.name = name;
        this.price = price;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public double getPrice() {
        return price;
    }
}
```

---

Functions, that receive `List<Fruit>` and retrieve fruits that reuiqred specific conditions.

Note that *price* is **double** value, hence it should be compared correctly, using `Double.compare(one, two) == 0` method instead of using `one == two`.

```
private static final Function<List<Fruit>, List<Fruit>> GET_CHEAPEST = fruits -> {
    final double minPrice = fruits.stream().mapToDouble(Fruit::getPrice).min().orElse(Double.NaN);
    return fruits.stream().filter(fruit -> Double.compare(fruit.getPrice(), minPrice) == 0).collect(Collectors.toList());
};

private static final Function<List<Fruit>, List<Fruit>> GET_MOST_EXPENSIVE = fruits -> {
    final double maxPrice = fruits.stream().mapToDouble(Fruit::getPrice).max().orElse(Double.NaN);
    return fruits.stream().filter(fruit -> Double.compare(fruit.getPrice(), maxPrice) == 0).collect(Collectors.toList());
};
```

---

This is method that use `Scanner` to receive all information about all fruits. Do not forget to close `Scanner`.

```
private static List<Fruit> getFruits() {
    try (Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in)) {
        System.out.print("Enter the number of items in your shopping list: ");
        int total = scan.nextInt();

        List<Fruit> fruits = new ArrayList<>(total);

        for (int i = 1; i <= total; i++) {
            System.out.println("Enter item " + i + ':');
            System.out.print("Name: ");
            String name = scan.nextLine();

            System.out.print("Price: ");
            double price = scan.nextDouble();

            fruits.add(new Fruit(name, price));

            System.out.println();
        }

        return fruits;
    }

}
```

---

And finally client code. I believe that now it is pretty simple to realize.

```
List<Fruit> fruits = getFruits();
List<Fruit> cheapestFruits = GET_CHEAPEST.apply(fruits);
List<Fruit> mostExpensiveFruits = GET_MOST_EXPENSIVE.apply(fruits);

System.out.println("Cheapest fruits:");
cheapestFruits.forEach(fruit -> System.out.format("%s costs %.2f\n", fruit.getName(), fruit.getPrice()));
System.out.println();
System.out.println("Most expensive fruits:");
mostExpensiveFruits.forEach(fruit -> System.out.format("%s costs %.2f\n", fruit.getName(), fruit.getPrice()));
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer. I'm a beginner and Lists haven't yet been covered in the course that I'm doing. That is why I have tried to solve this problem using arrays. My problem is that I cannot understand why the code I've written won't identify the correct item from the shopping list as being the most/least expensive

Answer (score 0):

So.. I took an alternative way to process the information. Which I believe is worth you looking at. Although it won't satisfy your problem it will create a working example.

1. Scanner or anything that involves parsing String to Integer/Double/Short/etc.. has the issue that the String must PERFECTLY equal that value.
2. In your example you do Scanner.parseDouble(String); The problem is if the user inputs a non decimal value. Your program will crash. On top of that if the decimal is out of precision it will return an invalid or non expected result.
3. To get around this we use a char array or a value type that far exceeds our needs. In my situation I used a long value. Which has a maximum numeric amount of 9,223,372,036,854,775,807. We don't need anywhere near that amount so it's safe to lock the item to maximum price of 999,999,999.99 and it'll fit millions of times into that value. Then when it comes time to display this value we can convert it into text useable for reading as a price.

   4. I also took on a non array approach to give you insight on another way to find, store, and display the lowest and highest cost items. I also gave you total items and total shopping cost. Hopefully you can use some of these examples for future code.
   5. Another thing to point out his how I converted the String of numbers to a value. There's many way to go about this, but given this situation I choose to loop backwards from the known decimal index or length of string if no decimal was given. We convert the character from 0-9 to a value of 0 to 9. This was done by taking it's char value and taking 48 off it. If the value didn't equal a number between 0 and 9 we skipped it. If it did though we added it to our total value. We started with 100 as our multiplier so 98.76 would give us 9800 price value.  Then we add the change which is 99 so gives us a total number of 9876. When we want to convert this into a price. We do 9876 / 100 = 98 and display the 98. Then take 9876 and minus (98 * 100) = 76. So then we display "." and "76". This gives us safe cost displaying and we can support any amount from 0 to 999,999,999.99 safely.

_

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ShoppingList
{
    private static long LOWEST_ITEM_COST = Long.MAX_VALUE;
    private static long HIGHEST_ITEM_COST = -1;

    private static long TOTAL_COST = 0;
    private static int TOTAL_ITEMS = 0;

    private static String LOWEST_ITEM_NAME;
    private static String HIGHEST_ITEM_NAME;

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        System.out.print("\nSyntax: FOODNAME PRICE, I.e. Apples $8.50");
        while (true)
        {
            Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

            System.out.print("\nEnter a food: ");

            String split[] = sc.nextLine().split(" ");

            if (split.length > 2)
            {

            }

            if (split.length == 2)
            {
                String name = split[0]; 

                int length = split[1].length();
                int decimal_position = -1;
                for (int j = length; --j >= 0; )
                {
                    if (split[1].charAt(j) == '.')
                    {
                        decimal_position = j;
                        break;
                    }
                }

                if (decimal_position != -1)
                    length = decimal_position;

                long dollars = 0;
                long change = 0;
                int place = 100;

                for (int c = length; --c >= 0; )
                {
                    int value = (int)split[1].charAt(c) - 48;

                    if (value < 0 || value > 10)
                        continue;

                    if (place == 1000000000) //1 Billion is too large to process stop here!
                    {
                        System.out.print("\nPrice Amount exceeds $999,999,999.99 limitation! You entered: " + split[1]);
                        continue;
                    }

                    value *= place;
                    place *= 10;
                    dollars += value;
                }

                place = 10;

                if (decimal_position != -1 && (split[1].length() - 3 >= decimal_position))
                {
                    for (int c = decimal_position; c < split[1].length(); ++c)
                    {
                        int value = (int)split[1].charAt(c) - 48;

                        if (value < 0 || value > 10)
                            continue;

                        value *= place;
                        place -= 9;
                        change += value;

                        if (place < 0)
                            break;
                    }       
                }

                System.out.print("\nItem: " + name + " was added to the shopping cart. Cost: $" + (dollars / 100) + '.' + ((change < 10) ? (change + '0') : (change)));

                dollars += change;

                if (dollars < LOWEST_ITEM_COST)
                {
                    LOWEST_ITEM_COST = dollars;
                    LOWEST_ITEM_NAME = name;
                }

                if (dollars > HIGHEST_ITEM_COST)
                {
                    HIGHEST_ITEM_COST = dollars;
                    HIGHEST_ITEM_NAME = name;
                }       

                TOTAL_ITEMS++;
                TOTAL_COST += dollars;
            } else {
                if (split.length == 1 && split[0].toLowerCase().contains("done"))
                {
                    break;
                }
                System.out.print("\nSyntax: FOODNAME PRICE, E.g. IceCream 8.50");
                System.out.print("\nTo Finish The Shopping List Simply type: DONE");
                continue;
            }
        }

        if (TOTAL_ITEMS == 0)
        {
            System.out.print("\nNothing Was Added To Your Shopping List Today..");
            return;
        }

        long dollars = HIGHEST_ITEM_COST / 100;
        long change = HIGHEST_ITEM_COST - (dollars * 100);

        System.out.print("\nHighest Cost Item: " + HIGHEST_ITEM_NAME + " , Costed: " + dollars + '.' + change + ((change < 10) ? '0' : ""));


        dollars = LOWEST_ITEM_COST / 100;
        change = LOWEST_ITEM_COST - (dollars * 100);

        System.out.print("\nLowest Cost Item: " + LOWEST_ITEM_NAME + " , Costed: " + dollars + '.' + change + ((change < 10) ? '0' : ""));

        dollars = TOTAL_COST / 100;
        change = TOTAL_COST - (dollars * 100);

        System.out.print("\nTotal Items Bought: " + TOTAL_ITEMS + " , With a total cost of $" + dollars + '.' + change + ((change < 10) ? '0' : ""));
    }
}
```